# Django admin removes selected choice in ModelChoiceField on edit?

Tags: python, django

I'm using `admin.TabularInline` in my admin code for which I've made a custom form.

```
class RateCardForm(forms.ModelForm):
    category = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=models.Category.objects.all(), label='Category')

    class Meta:
        model = models.RateCard
        fields = ('category')

class RateCardInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = models.RateCard
    form = RateCardForm
    extra = 3
```

The problem is that after I've saved my model instance, whenever I edit the model instance, it would remove the pre-selected choice and I'll have to select the choice again. Any ideas as to how to stop it?

Also for `ModelChoiceField` if I don't specify the label, then it would come up as `None` on admin page, but I don't need to specify it for `admin.StackedInline`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To preselect the currently selected category instance you can set its primary key to the field's `initial` value by overriding `__init__()` on the `ModelForm`:

```
class RateCardForm(forms.ModelForm):
    category = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=models.Category.objects.all(), label='Category')

    class Meta:
        model = models.RateCard
        fields = ('category')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RateCardForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        instance = kwargs.get('instance')
        # Instance will be None for the empty extra rows.
        if instance:
            selected_pk = # query the primary key of the currently selected category here
            self.fields['category'].initial = selected_pk
```

Comment: BTW, why does it remove the selected choice? The text fields don't go empty!

Comment: It is a CharField on RateCard, therefore shouldn't Django be able to remember the saved value?

Comment: Will try to look into it in more detail this afternoon. From a quick test I can reproduce the behavior you get. My first guess is that by defining the `ModelChoiceField` manually Django also puts the user in control of managing its initial value (i.e. that by changing the `CharField`'s widget to a select field Django doesn't know where to put that initial value).

Comment: As a side question, I assume there is a specific reason not to use a `ForeignKey` to relate `RateCard` to the `Category`?

Comment: Basically i wanted to limit the choices while selecting therefore i used a Charfield. And then in the form i used a modelchoicefield. I don't know if foreign key choices can also be limited

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the None header behavior as well?

Comment: Regarding the filtering of options shown in the foreign key dropdown. This is rather common and Django has [`formfield_for_foreignkey()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey) to hook into these available options. This would go into `RateCardInline` in the example above. If you try it that way your selection should remain preselected correctly.

Comment: Thanks will try that! Were u able to reproduce the None header bug?

Comment: Yes, I get the same result here. `None` for `TabularInline` and the field name for `StackedInline`. Googled a bit but didn't find any hints if that is a bug, a technical limitation or expected. Maybe it is worth bringing it up in the #django IRC channel and possibly in the [ticketing system](https://code.djangoproject.com/).